# Route Finding on SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

So, I have this OpenFlights data and I am trying to add the functionality of route finding that is, if two countries/airports are connected via intermediate stops, I still need to return them along with direct flights. I am planning to add a new column path which contains which countries it went through. it would be null for direct paths. So far, I have tried CTEs but it's not really working and running infinitely. If someone could view my code and add suggestions, that would be great! I am doing this using core PostgreSQL

My SQL that isn't working

I am not getting error message but it's running infinitely. Desired result would be the details of all flights from United Kingdom to United States which go directly or indirectly

```
WITH RECURSIVE flight_paths AS (
  SELECT r."Source Airport ID", r."Destination Airport ID", a1."Country" AS source_country, a2."Country" AS destination_country, a1."Name" AS source_airport, a2."Name" AS destination_airport, r."Airline ID", CAST(a1."Name" || '->' || a2."Name" AS VARCHAR(255)) AS path
  FROM Routes r
  JOIN Airports a1 ON r."Source Airport ID" = a1."Airport ID"
  JOIN Airports a2 ON r."Destination Airport ID" = a2."Airport ID"
  WHERE a1."Country" = 'United Kingdom'
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT fp."Source Airport ID", r."Destination Airport ID", fp.source_country, a2."Country" AS destination_country, fp.source_airport, a2."Name" AS destination_airport, r."Airline ID", CAST(fp.path || '->' || a2."Name" AS VARCHAR(255))
  FROM flight_paths fp
  JOIN Routes r ON fp."Destination Airport ID" = r."Source Airport ID"
  JOIN Airports a2 ON r."Destination Airport ID" = a2."Airport ID"
  WHERE fp.destination_country != 'United States' AND POSITION(a2."Name" IN fp.path) = 0 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Routes WHERE "Source Airport ID" = r."Destination Airport ID")
)
SELECT * FROM flight_paths WHERE destination_country = 'United States';
```

Schema

```
Airline (
   "Airline ID" INTEGER,
   "Name" VARCHAR(255),
   "Alias" VARCHAR(255),
   "IATA" VARCHAR(3),
   "ICAO" VARCHAR(4),
   "Callsign" VARCHAR(255),
   "Country" VARCHAR(255),
   "Active" VARCHAR(1)
);

Airports (
   "Airport ID" INTEGER,
   "Name" VARCHAR(255),
   "City" VARCHAR(255),
   "Country" VARCHAR(255),
   "IATA" VARCHAR(3),
   "ICAO" VARCHAR(4),
   "Latitue" DECIMAL,
   "Longitude" DECIMAL,
   "Altitude" INTEGER,
   "Timezone" INTEGER,
   "DST" VARCHAR(1),
   "Tz Database Timezone" VARCHAR(255),
   "Type" VARCHAR(255),
   "Source" VARCHAR(255)
);

Country (
   "Name" VARCHAR(255),
   "iso_code" VARCHAR(2),
   "dafif_code" VARCHAR(2)
);


Plane (
   "Name" VARCHAR(255),
   "IATA" VARCHAR(3),
   "ICAO" VARCHAR(4)
);

Routes (
   "Airline" VARCHAR(255),
   "Airline ID" INTEGER,
   "Source Airport" VARCHAR(255),
   "Source Airport ID" INTEGER,
   "Destination Airport" VARCHAR(255),
   "Destination Airport ID" INTEGER,
   "Codeshare" VARCHAR(255),
   "Stops" INTEGER,
   "Equipment" VARCHAR(255),
   "Departure Time" TIME,
   "Arrival Time" TIME,
   "Price" INTEGER
);
```

Comment: Hi - can you update your question to explain, in business terms, how you would find a flight path between 2 airports? I think you'll find that as the number of airports increases the number of possible flight paths that need to be checked will increase exponentially, as will the time taken to generate the solution - effectively there is no good solution to this type of problem and a pure SQL solution is unlikely to be feasible. Not my area of expertise so happy to be corrected but I think this is a variation on the Travelling Salesman problem

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment! I'm trying to find paths by joining the tables such that if a flight lands at an airport and departs from that airport only, it has to be connected to the first original destination.

Comment: "If a flight lands at an airport and departs from that airport only" means that the flight must have just flown in a circle - taking off and landing at the same airport. As this is probably not what you mean, it emphasises why I suggested you update your question (not add information in comments) that clearly demonstrates how a flight path should be found. It would be helpful if you showed some worked examples i.e. given a list of airports, how you would determine which of them were included in a specific flight path